How do I set the 4x4 post for a hand rail on a set of deck stairs with a gas line running underground beneath the stairs?
How do I set the 4x4 post for a handrail on a set of deck stairs with a gas line running underground beneath the stairs? It's the main gas line from the street to the house, so I know it's there, and I've contacted 811 to mark the lines before I dig.
I have to rebuild these steps, and I'm wondering how to make sure the railing posts are secure enough.  They are currently notched out and attached to the strings, but they wobble so much as to be useless.  If I can't dig because of the gas line that runs under the stairs, what's the best way to rebuild this?


First, a few misconception adjustments.

Stairway posts usually aren't anchored in the ground. Unless they're also supporting the stairs, as a deck post would, they're simply integrated into the stair framing. Most stairs I've seen or built just rest on the ground as yours do, though.

Modern stairways usually require riser boards, making them "closed". This is to prevent a simple slip from becoming a broken tibia.

As such, there's usually plenty of box structure in the stairs to support a post. With the tread, riser, and a bottom plate or blocking underneath you have a fairly robust assembly to which you can mount your post.

Even if you don't install riser boards, you can accomplish similar rigidity with some strategically placed blocking and/or a bottom plate.


So, build your stairs, but leave off the bottom tread(s). Install your post with precise fitment and appropriate fasteners. See how it feels. Add blocking to support the outer stringers as needed--sometimes crossblocks on either side of the post are ideal. Then install your bottom treads, which usually need to be notched for the post if you have an end overhang to match your nosing.
You aren't going to achieve rock solid, but it'll be fairly stiff and up to the task of supporting users.

As a comment it is problematic to set the end of the stairs on a set of pavers or on an on-ground concrete pad when the top end of the steps may be attached to the house which may be on a "below frost line footing". It really would require that the stairs be set upon similar footings as the house/porch structure so there is not the possibility of differential frost heaving occurring.

Then it should've been a comment. The question isn't about supporting the stairs, though, and I've never seen an inspector require footings there.
